# Разделение большой строки в DropDownList ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть DropDownList, но айтемы(строки) которые в нем помещены очень длинные.

Как разделять длинные строки? Что то типо \n нужно

Моя проблема представлена на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 контроллер
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Id_category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Cat");
        ViewBag.Id_description = new SelectList(db.Descriptions, "Id", "Descript");
        ViewBag.Id_manufacturer = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "Id", "Firm");
        ViewBag.Id_name = new SelectList(db.Names, "Id", "Tool");
        return View();
    }

 модель
 public partial class Equipment
{
    public int ToolID { get; set; }
    public int Id_name { get; set; }
    public int Id_description { get; set; }
    public int Id_category { get; set; }
    public int Id_manufacturer { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Цена (руб)")]
    [Required]
    [Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Проверьте правильность ввода")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Description Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
}



  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_description", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ASP. NET MVC или Web Forms?  Приведите код модели/контроллера/code behind.

Comment: Пишу на mvc asp.net

Comment: Тогда код модели и контроллера -  в студию

Comment: Буду добавлять в основную тему, чтобы табуляция кода была

Comment: И view тоже покажите

Comment: Все, добавил весь шаблон нужного действия

Comment: @klutch1991 при чем тут модель и контроллер вообще?

Comment: Я вот тоже думаю, какой смысл. Если визуальная часть - вьюшка

Comment: в общем не получится у вас обычным образом это сделать, либо сами рисуйте, либо [вот вариант предлагают](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3587965/1216425)

Comment: Я бы попробовал добавить readonly свойство в модель, которое будет обрезать ваш Id_description до заданной длины и возвращать обрезанное значение. Либо создайте свой helper,  который будет принимать в качестве одного из параметров,  скажем,  максимальную длину строки для отображения в списке.

Comment: @teran, у Вас есть варианты без изменения кода модели или самого helper? Если бы вьюшка не компилировалаcь razor перед отправкой клиенту,  то вариантов решить проблему на js море.  А в этом случае - даже не знаю.  Мне в голову ничего не приходит.

Comment: @klutch1991 на js и надо решать, модель и хэлпер тут вообще не при делах, вопрос только в представлении. При чем тут компиляция вьюшки вообще? Вопрос автора ведь не втом, как обрезать длинную строку, чтобы она влезала в ширину, а в том чтобы показать ее целиком с word-wrap.